# How to update systemd-libs on ubuntu AWS EC2 instance running GitLab omnibus safely?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Our security scanner detected a high vulnerability on `systemd-libs` and I need to update it without making our GitLab omnibus getting affected by it. What will be the right steps or commands to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the steps.

1. Rename `gitlab_gitlab-ee.list` file to `gitlab_gitlab-ee.list.disabled` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory to prevent the os upgrade.
2. Run: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver OpenPGP Keyserver  --recv-keys 3F01618A51312F3F`
3. Run: `sudo apt update`
4. Run: `sudo apt upgrade`
5. Run: `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
6. Run: `sudo apt reboot`
7. Run: `sudo apt do-release-upgrade`

   - During the upgrade, it may ask a question related to `sshd_config`. It might be better to keep current config instead of applying the new package.
   - It will ask to reboot the server. You should proceed with that.
8. Once the server is back online, run: `sudo apt autoremove`
9. Rename `gitlab_gitlab-ee.list.disabled` file to `gitlab_gitlab-ee.list`.

Note: It will cause some downtime but the GitLab omnibus will not get affected.